Airflow DAG Import Error Avro - installed everywhere
import avro.schema
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'avro'

I have this error when I try to import a DAG in Airflow.
I have avro installed in the docker image as shown below:
Installed /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/avro-1.11.3-py3.12.egg
Processing dependencies for avro==1.11.3
Finished processing dependencies for avro==1.11.3

I have also installed the right dependencies for that docker image and its also specified when I create it in the requirements.txt
avro==1.11.3

When I try to run it from Visual Studio (inside the airflow docker image) it runs fine, doesn't get imported in Airflow.
It did the same thing with Spark, then converted all my code to Pandas.
I cannot get around it and I need some ideas!
Python 3.12.4
Created dags from Visual Studio.
Tested DAGs within the Docker Airflow CLI (cmd whatever).
Tests are fine.
Try to open it in Airflow, it does not import the AVRO module.
It did the same thing with Spark, then converted all my code to Pandas.
Tried uninstalling, reinstalling, rebuilding image, docker compose up down left right.

Ensure that -avro is installed correctly:
python -c "import avro; print(avro.version)"

Yep I recieve 1.11.3 which is the correct version.

Do you confirmed that avro is installed in the correct environmment? And if the PYTHONPATH is correctly set in the Airflow configuration to include the correct path where avro is installed?

You can check the path using:
-PYTHONPATH=/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH

I did and I still get the same import error.

If you're using a custom Dockerfile, ensure avro is installed during the image build process:
FROM apache/airflow:2.3.3
USER root
RUN pip install avro==1.11.3
USER airflow                                                Rebuild and restart docker containers:docker-compose down
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d

I have it included in the custom files too. I check the cli in docker inside the container with pip list and avro is installed. The weird this is, when I run it from Visual Studio it does not complain, when I open Airflow it does not import it.

If you had setted all this it is supposed to work, are you sure the python version used in VS is the same used in Airflow? Maybe there are a misconfiguration in the environmment or in the path

Thats what I think could happen too, do you mind giving me a direction on how to check this?
Never used Airflow or Docker before, hence I am asking. Coming from Jupyter notebooks where everything gets installed in a cluster.
